# Trend up and down function for R

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using quantmod for backtesting and have a column with SMA values

```
sma<-SMA(Cl(symbol),20)
```

I want to know whether any trend up or down fucntion is available for R to find out the trend of sma

eg.   trendup(sma) gives TRUE if sma is trending upwards or else false

Comment: You can check for functions using `library(sos); ?findFn`

Comment: Doesn't look like there is one. `library(quantmod); apropos("trend") ##[1] "prop.trend.test"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Trending" is not well defined. You must choose thresholds for magnitude and timespan. A simple trend indicator would be any magnitude for 1 period: `sign(diff(sma))`.

See `?TTR::ADX` and its *See Also* section for some different ways to measure trend.